# How to make a case insensitive active search in django with htmx

Tags: python, django-views, tailwind-css, htmx

I got this code that works to make active search. I have it working but the problem is that it cannot search well. If it's a small letter and you type capital it doesn't recognize. It is case sensitive. How can I make it case insensitive???

```
@require_http_methods(['POST'])
def search(request):
    res_todos = []
    search = request.POST['search']
    if len(search) == 0:
        return render(request, 'todo.html', {'todos':[]})
    for i in list(Persons.objects.values()):
        if search in i['title']:
            res_todos.append(i)
    return render(request, 'todo.html', {'todos': res_todos})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can let the database do the work for you and thus filter with:

```
@require_http_methods(['POST'])
def search(request):
    search = request.POST['search']
    qs = Persons.objects.none()
    if search:
        qs = Persons.objects.filter(title__icontains=search)
    return render(request, 'todo.html', {'todos': qs})
```

Usually for searching with a query, a GET request is used instead of a POST request.

---

> **Note**: normally a Django model is given a *singular* name, so `Person` instead of <s>`Persons`</s>.